# Is there any way to get DDESpy to display complete untruncated messages? if not, what tool could I use for this?

Tags: dde

When monitoring DDE messages with DDESpy, I can capture what I am looking for, however DDESpy truncates it:

```
[1ff8:212781728] CB(Execute, fmt=0x0("?"), 39002100, c001("WWW_OpenURL") 0(""), 3d003b00, 0, 0)=3e004300
    Input data=
    22 00 68 00 74 00 74 00 70 00 3a 00 2f 00 2f 00    ".h.t.t.p.:././. 6e 00 65 00 77 00 73 00 2e 00 79 00 63 00 6f 00    n.e.w.s...y.c.o.
    ...
```

Now, this is truly annoying, because what I am really after are the parameters at the end of the input data (after the ....)

How could I get that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The location of the DDEML API is important to DDE monitoring
>   applications. DDEspy from Microsoft and our Dynamic Data Studio use
>   the DDEML APPCLASS_MONITOR facility. Message hooks can read the memory
>   handles of the data attached to a WM_DDE_xxx message, but for 32-bit
>   applications the handles have no meaning in other process spaces. The
>   32-bit version of the DDEML API extracts and passes some data to a
>   monitoring application, but only the first 28 bytes. There is no way
>   to obtain more than this.

Apparently this is why I am seeing only the first 28 bytes. I guess I am out of luck.

Source: http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/ddeinfo.html